# How can I make this search query more efficient?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

I have a somewhat convoluted search query that I would like to make more efficient (if possible).

Here is the entire code for this query:

```
Route::post('api/search/{startRow}', function($startRow)
{
    $category = Category::where('name', '=', Input::get('category'))->first();

    // Initialize query
    $query = Resource::with('alerts', 'alerts.type', 'user', 'category', 'comments', 'comments.comments', 'ratings')
        ->where('duplicate', '=', 0);

    // Limit search results
    if(Input::get('show'))
    {
        $show = Input::get('show');
        switch ($show) {
            case 'verified':
                $query->where('verified', '=', true);
                break;

            case 'unverified':
                $query->where('verified', '=', false);
                break;

            case 'alerted':
                $query->has('alerts');
                break;

            case 'unalerted':
                $query->has('alerts', '=', 0);
                break;

            default:
                // The default will be 'all' (show all results)
                break;
        }
    }

    if($category->name != "everything")
        $query->where('category_id', '=', $category->id);


    // Sort the search results
    if(Input::get('sort_type'))
    {
        $sort_by = Input::get('sort_type');

        switch ($sort_by)
        {
            case 'relevance':
                break;

            case 'name_asc':
                $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
                break;

            case 'name_desc':
                $query->orderBy('name', 'desc');
                break;

            case 'rating_high':
                $query
                    ->leftJoin('ratings', 'ratings.ratable_id', '=', 'resources.id')
                    ->where('ratings.ratable_type', '=', 'Resource')
                    ->orderBy(DB::raw('avg(ratings.score)'), 'desc')
                    ->orderBy(DB::raw('count(ratings.score)'), 'desc')
                    ->select('resources.*')
                    ->groupBy('resources.id');
                break;

            case 'rating_low':
                $query
                    ->leftJoin('ratings', 'ratings.ratable_id', '=', 'resources.id')
                    ->where('ratings.ratable_type', '=', 'Resource')
                    ->orderBy(DB::raw('avg(ratings.score)'), 'asc')
                    ->orderBy(DB::raw('count(ratings.score)'), 'asc')
                    ->select('resources.*')
                    ->groupBy('resources.id');
                break;

            case 'date_new':
                $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                break;

            case 'date_old':
                $query->orderBy('created_at', 'asc');
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // Search by keyword(s)
    if(Input::get('keyword'))
    {
        $search = Input::get('keyword');
        $searchTerms = explode(' ', $search);

        $fields = array(
            'resources.description',
            'resources.website',
            'resources.additional_info');

        foreach ($searchTerms as $term)
        {
            $query->where('resources.name', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');

            foreach ($fields as $field)
            {
                $query->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
            }
        }
    }


    // Search by tag(s)
    if(Input::get('tags'))
    {
        $tags = Input::get('tags');

        $query
            ->select('resources.*')
            ->join('taggables', 'taggables.taggable_id', '=', 'resources.id')
            ->join('tags', 'taggables.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
            ->whereIn('tags.id', $tags)
            ->groupBy('resources.id')
            ->havingRaw('COUNT(resources.id)=?', array(count($tags)));
    }

    // Total number of results
    $count = $query->get()->count();

    // Page number and offset for infinite scroll
    $query->skip($startRow)->take(10);

    // Get our first set of tiles
    $tiles = $query->get();

    return Response::json(array(
        'count' => $count,
        'tiles' => $tiles->toArray()));
});
```

You see, I have a database filled with "resources" which (through pivot tables) are related to tags, comments and alerts, and I want these resources searchable on any of the following criteria:
Text contained in resource model itself, tags associated with the resource, and number of associated alerts.

One problem I'm having is that the keyword search doesn't seem to be "accurate" enough. When I search for, say, "Venture Firm", there are a few results returned before the one which contains the phrase "Venture Firm" - a user will definitely not expect this.

Another problem I'm having related to selecting a "show" type (i.e. `$query->has('alerts')` if user only wants to see resources with alerts). If I enter a keyword search and a show type (like above), the results will still contain resources that do not have alerts (even though I specified I only want resources that have alerts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevance search depends on your db engine.

But for the keyword search, you have it wrong:

```
foreach ($fields as $field)
{
    $query->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
}
```

This piece adds `WHERE ....long list of clauses here.... OR something LIKE %term% ...` what basically breaks the whole thing.

Instead you need this:

```
$fields = array(
 'resources.name',
 'resources.description',
 'resources.website',
 'resources.additional_info'
);

$query->where(function ($q) use ($searchTerms, $fields) {
  foreach ($searchTerms as $term)
  {
    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        $q->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
    }
  }
});
```

This will wrap your `OR .. OR ..` clauses in `AND ( .. OR .. )`.

Comment: Thanks - this has helped! Looking at [http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres) was also useful. There are a few syntax errors in your code but I understand.

Comment: @cornflakes24 I don't think there are any syntax errors there, apart from `$q` and `$query`, which was wrong indeed, and missing parens too. Suppose this is what you meant

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant! I guess the mix-up with `$q` and `$query` would be a semantic error and the missing parenthesis would be a syntax error, no?